# Vue PWA login works in dev but returns 401 in production

Tags: django, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a `Vue.js PWA` with a `Django Rest Framework` backend which works correctly locally on my laptop (using a browser). When I deploy it to production it continues to work correctly when I log in using a browser, however it fails to login when opened as a PWA (ie: on a phone or a PWA saved in a browser).

Here's my login code:

```js
      axios
        .post("/api/get-token/", user)
        .then(res => {
          localStorage.setItem('user-token', res.data.token);
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = res.data.token;
          commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, res.data);
          resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit(AUTH_ERROR, err);
          reject(err);
        });
```

As mentioned, everything works locally and in production when logging in via a browser. The problem comes when trying to log in using the PWA.

When trying to login to the PWA, I get the following:

```
POST https://www.example.com/api/get-token/ 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Doing a console log of the error received from the server I get:

```
{
  detail: "Invalid token header. No credentials provided."
  __proto__: Object
  status: 401
  statusText: "Unauthorized"
  headers: {allow: "POST, OPTIONS", connection: "keep-alive", content-length: "59", content-type: "application/json", date: "Thu, 06 Feb 2020 15:00:11 GMT", …}
  config:
    url: "/api/get-token/"
    method: "post"
    data: "{"username":"test@example.com","password":"password"}"
    headers:
      Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      Authorization: "Token "
      Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
   __proto__: Object
  transformRequest: [ƒ]
  transformResponse: [ƒ]
  timeout: 0
  adapter: ƒ (t)
  xsrfCookieName: "csrftoken"
  xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken"
  maxContentLength: -1
  validateStatus: ƒ (t)
}
```

In production, the following works:

1. Log into the site using a browser on my laptop or on a phone.
2. Then open the PWA. This works correctly and I can continue using the PWA.

The only issue comes when trying to log in using the PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out the issue. For some reason the following was being POSTed in the header: `Authorization: "Token "`.

This is really strange because when logging in using the `/api/get-token/` there is no token required since this is the login route. Also, it works perfectly from a browser. The only issue is when trying from a PWA.

Anyway, changing the header to explicitly have no value for `Authorization` fixed the issue as follows: `Authorization: ""`

Answer (score 0):

Can you log in on a phone locally? I had this problem too once, the problem was that the frontend and backend were not running on the same host. This solved my problem:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Locally everything works correctly. I am already using the devServer proxy config options. The problem comes with production. The vue app and the Django backend are running on the same server in production and once logged in everything works correctly,...its just the login that doesnt work.